# Error while enabling CORS on Matlab production server

Tags: javascript, matlab, cors

I am trying to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)on the MATLAB Production Server to use it with Javascript application, I am using R2015a version but when I run the server by `mps-start`, I get this error:

```
Error: unrecognized option: --cors-allowed-origins
: unrecognized flag
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the option in your [`server_name/config/main_config` file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/mps/server/customize-the-configuration-file.html).

That way it gets picked up no matter what `mps-*` command you use.

Comment: I think that the problem was in the version, javascript was supported starting from 2016 , i ll download it and retry it.

Comment: OK yeah didn’t know that but if that’s the case then yeah it makes sense to update your kit

Answer (score 2):

In general the method described by @sideshowbarker is how you would pass options to `mps-start`, rather than as command-line options.

However, I believe the particular option you mention, `cors-allowed-origins`, doesn't exist in R2015a - it was introduced as part of the RESTful API to MPS in R2016a.